# i want to add attachment file from my computer in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfU8N.png)while clicking attachments select button in adding new item in custom data list, I want to add files from windows explorer in client side instead of from server.

abve image is adding attachments from server i dont want that, i want to add files from windows explorer in client pc.

Comment: Could you upgrade to version 5.2?https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-6467-alfresco-community-edition-201611-ea-release-notes

Comment: Could you please explain what you want ? It is hard to understand from the information you give.

Comment: while adding attachment in datalist form,how to upload attachment file from local client system.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Alfresco 5.1**: [`POST /alfresco/service/api/upload`](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/references/RESTful-UploadUploadPost.html). In this version the [new REST API](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/) doesn't include methods for nodes.
2. **Alfresco [5.2 EA](https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-6467-alfresco-community-edition-201611-ea-release-notes)**: the new REST endpoint [`POST /nodes/{nodeId}/children`](https://wildloop.github.io/alfresco-rest-api-explorer-dev-demo/#!/nodes/createNode), that supports file upload using multipart/form-data.

   ```
   curl -X POST 
       --header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
       --header 'Accept: application/json' 
       --header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' 
       -d '{"name":"my-new-file"}' 
       'http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/parent-node-id/children'
   ```